# Displaying content from Parse into a UITableViewController using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

I have been following a tutorial on Youtube which helps you create an app like Twitter using **Parse** as a backend service. So far I was able to add things to classes in Parse but I was either not able to retrieve them or display them in my table view.

I believe this is where my mistake is:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell:messageTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath!) as messageTableViewCell

        let sweet:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject

        cell.messageTextView.alpha = 0
        cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0

        cell.messageTextView.text = sweet.objectForKey("content") as String


        var dataFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dataFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
        cell.timestampLabel.text = dataFormatter.stringFromDate(sweet.createdAt)

        var findSweeter:PFQuery = PFUser.query()
        findSweeter.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: sweet.objectForKey("username").objectId)

        findSweeter.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if error == nil{
                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser
                cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
                    cell.messageTextView.alpha = 1
                    cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                })
            }
        }


        return cell
    }
```

**If you could help me figure this out I would really appreciate it, also please try to be detailed.**

The error might also be here, I'm completely lost so I will post this as well!

**func loadData(){**
        timelineData.removeAllObjects()

```
    var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages")

    findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
        (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

        if error == nil{
            for object in objects{
                let message:PFObject = object as PFObject
                self.timelineData.addObject(message)
            }

            let array:NSArray = self.timelineData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
            self.timelineData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    }
}
```